# Grouping similar numbers into brackets

Tags: java

I have recently got into java and I need help with a basic program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Random gen = new Random();
int roll = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int[] array = new int[20];
    // Replacing all the numbers of the array to random ones
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
        roll = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
        array[i] = roll;
    }
    // Bracketing all repeating numbers
    for (int i=0; i<19; i++){
        if (array[i] == array[i++]){
            System.out.print("(");
        }
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        if (array[i] == array[i--]){
            System.out.print(")");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

All this code does is take the random die roll and bracket all the numbers that are the same:

13(66)5(2222)(66)71

However, all it does with this code is bracket all the numbers instead of the ones that are the same:

(1)(3)(6)(6)(5)(2)(2)(2)(2)(6)(6)(7)(1)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look up the difference between `i++` and `i+1`. One computes a value, the other changes the state of your program. You need state change in your loop expression and value computation in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is only checking numbers immediately prior to and immediately after the indexed number in `array[i]`.

You could create a second loop inside the first to iterate over all of the numbers in the array to check for a match.

If you do so, you'll need to keep track of the matching numbers with some other mechanism.  Immediately printing out a parenthesis as you're currently doing will be problematic with an inner loop.

A simple method to consider is another array that keeps track of whether there was a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are recently got into Java try to avoid i++ and ++i within square brackets.  You can solve this problem with a boolean variable that indicates if there is already a bracket open.

After generate random numbers, try this:

```
    boolean openBracket=false;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
        if (array[i] == array[i+1] && !openBracket){
            System.out.print("(");
            openBracket=true;
        }
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        if(array[i] != array[i+1] && openBracket){
            System.out.print(")");
            openBracket=false;
        }
      }
```